# How to making a gpg signed commit with gitpython?

Tags: gitpython

I'm using

```
from git import Repo

index=repo.index
index.add(filename)
index.commit(commit_message)
```

But my commits don't have my gpg signature. How can I make a commit that is signed with the gpg signature? This is important for me to make automated signed commits, that can be pushed to the remote as the remote is set up to only accept signed commits.

Thanks for your help.